# Не удается скомпилировать проект после смены разрядности системы

Tags: c#, компиляция, opencv

Делал программу на opencv ... все работало нормально , потом переустановил винду и после компиляции выдает

1. Предупреждение

> Несоответствие
>       между архитектурой процессора
>       проекта "MSIL", построение которого
>       выполняется, и архитектурой
>       процессора ссылки "VideoInputSharp,
>       Version=1.0.3575.2535,
>       Culture=neutral,
>       processorArchitecture=x86", "x86".
>       Это несоответствие может привести к
>       ошибкам во время выполнения.
>       Попробуйте изменить целевую
>       архитектуру процессора для проекта с
>       помощью диспетчера конфигураций,
>       чтобы согласовать архитектуры
>       процессоров для проекта и ссылок,
>       или используйте зависимость от
>       ссылок с архитектурой процессора,
>       соответствующей целевой архитектуре
>       процессора проекта.   OpenCvSharp.Test

и соответствующею ошибку при запуске

> opencvsharp error . не удается загрузить Dll opencv_core245"

Answer (score 4):

В свойствах проекта выставите ту же архитектуру, для которой используются библиотеки, либо замените библиотеки на те, которые соответствуют вашей архитектуре.